# Kotlin - How to read from file asynchronously?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is there any kotlin idiomatic way to read a file content's asynchronously? I couldn't find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A least as of Java 7 (which is where Android is stuck), there isn't any API that would tap into the low-level async file IO support (like io_uring). There is a class called `AsynchronousFileChannel`, but, as its docs state,

> An `AsynchronousFileChannel` is associated with a thread pool to which tasks are submitted to handle I/O events and dispatch to completion handlers that consume the results of I/O operations on the channel.

That makes it no better than the following, bog-standard Kotlin idiom:

```
launch {
    val contents = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        FileInputStream("filename.txt").use { it.readBytes() }
    }
    processContents(contents)
}
go_on_with_other_stuff_while_file_is_loading()
```

This uses Kotlin's own dedicated IO thread pool and unblocks the UI thread. If you're on Android, that is your actual concern, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Java NIO Asynchronous Channel is the tool you want.
Check out this `AsynchronousFileChannel.aRead` extension function from [coroutine example](https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/io/io.kt):

```
suspend fun AsynchronousFileChannel.aRead(buf: ByteBuffer): Int =
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        read(buf, 0L, Unit, object : CompletionHandler<Int, Unit> {
            override fun completed(bytesRead: Int, attachment: Unit) {
                cont.resume(bytesRead)
            }

            override fun failed(exception: Throwable, attachment: Unit) {
                cont.resumeWithException(exception)
            }
        })
    }
```

You just open an `AsynchronousFileChannel` then call this `aRead()` in a coroutine,

```
val channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get(fileName))
try {
    val buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096)
    val bytesRead = channel.aRead(buf)
} finally {
    channel.close()
}
```

It's an essential function, don't know why it is not part of coroutine-core lib.

Comment: Quoting the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html): "An `AsynchronousFileChannel` is associated with a thread pool to which tasks are submitted to handle I/O events and dispatch to completion handlers that consume the results of I/O operations on the channel." Doesn't seem like any improvement over the standard blocking IO, except when you're in Java and want some more convenience.

Comment: `An AsynchronousFileChannel is associated with a thread pool` doesn't mean it uses blocking IO to do the job. In fact, it states that it uses the thread pool to "handle I/O events and dispatch to completion handlers". A more clear statement from [OpenJDK doc](https://openjdk.org/projects/nio/resources/AsynchronousIo.html) is "An asynchronous channel group associated with a fixed thread pool of size N, submits N tasks that wait on I/O or completion events from the **kernel**."

Comment: So it blocks N threads for N tasks, right? Non-blocking workloads are handled with just one event thread, and it blocks only when there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 2):

[javasync/RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) uses Java NIO Asynchronous Channel to provide a non-blocking API to read and write a file content's asynchronously, including kotlin idiomatic way. Next you have two examples: one reading/writing in bulk through coroutines, and other iterating lines through an asynchronous Kotlin Flow:

```kotlin
suspend fun copyNio(from: String, to: String) {
  val data = Path(from).readText() // suspension point
  Path(to).writeText(data)         // suspension point
}

fun printLinesFrom(filename: String) {
  Path(filename)
    .lines()   // Flow<String>
    .onEach(::println)
    .collect() // block if you want to wait for completion

}
```

Disclaimer I am the author and main contributor of [javasync/RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo)